# Liberty add something like "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=xxx"

Tags: java, xml, configuration, installation

I am doing the project migration, using the **Liberty** web server.
We need to add "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=xxx" config to the server/project but I don't know where to setup. Is it set to server.xml? Or somewhere else?
Could anyone provide the way to add the config? We don't want to amend any program.
Thanks in advance.

Walter/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by editing either the **server.xml** file or another XML file that is included in server.xml at run time.

**Installing or configuring**

https://wiki.openntf.org/display/CW/Installing+and+Configuring+Websphere+Liberty+Server

**By Liberty configuration with dropins files by using developer tools**

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/t_config_dropins_folder.html

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a file named `jvm.options`at the same level as the `server.xml`file and add a line with `-Djava.security.auth.login.config=xxx`

Another option is to create a file named `bootstrap.properties`and add `java.security.auth.login.config=xxx` in it. Every property in the `bootstrap.properties` file is automatically passed as a java property

More info [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_admin_customvars.html)